# vertical alignment for Label, DIV and Span in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm using third party libraries like Kendo which output various types of HTML elements when they render.

So you might end up with a scenario such as this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>label text</label>
        <div>muli select widget</div>
        <span>date selector</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

NB! Assume I don't have control over the HTML rendered from these widgets/third party tools.

The problem is vertical alignment for the scenario above. I've created a JSFiddle which shows how the label doesn't vertically align properly. See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tMJFF/

How would I get all three these elements to vertically align perfectly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical align img and text inside <p>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219324/vertical-align-img-and-text-inside-p)

Answer (score 2):

Use inline-block property on all elements

```
label,
.div-input,
.span-input{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6vQ4Q/

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned Kendo, so I'd recommend using whatever selectors they have decorating the `ul` and do something like :

```
ul.kendo-selector-class-of-choice li * {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display : inline; /* for lte IE7 only */
}
```

Since you aren't in control of the elements being created, this could change with different implementations/version updates of the decorating client side library (in this case Kendo).  The `*` covers that and although arguably a hungry selector its scope is limited by the `.kendo-selector-class`

The below works in Chrome and IE10, but jsfiddle a bit tricky to browser test for IE8 since it doesn't render properly itself... but if you do test further you'd find you'll have to use something like `display:inline` if you're going down to the lovely land of IE7-.

http://jsfiddle.net/tMJFF/11/

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `vertical-align:middle;`

Here is referenced [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tMJFF/2/)

```
label {
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:20px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.div-input {
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-right:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    box-model:collapse-box
}
.span-input {
    vertical-align:middle;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label {
    line-height:20px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

vertical align all elements in li to middle.

```
ul li *{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` css property aligning your tags vertically so simply use  :

```
label,div,span{
    vertical-align :middle
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tMJFF/6/)

Comment: Thanks, like with @Stephen I'll give this one a try